# Unexpected replacement in R gsub regular expression

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to replace y in the following string, but not if it's in combination with %. The following regex works fine for finding the pattern:

```
gsub(pattern = "([^%]y)", replacement = "*", "%x%xxxx_y_%y%y")
# [1] "%x%xxxx*_%y%y"
```

but replaces two characters (_y) instead just of one (y), as I would have expected. 
What's wrong?

Any help appreciated!
Andri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Change the parentheses in the regular expression as shown and make the corresponding change to the replacement string as follows:

```
gsub("([^%])y", "\\1", "%x%xxxx_y_%y%y")
## [1] "%x%xxxx__%y%y"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
([^%])y
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AQUDSLEHSzZdGgo4)

**2)**  It could be done with exactly your regular expression using gsubfn:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("([^%]y)", ~ substr(x, 1, 1), "%x%xxxx_y_%y%y")
## [1] "%x%xxxx__%y%y"
```

Here is a visualizatino of the regular expression:

```
([^%]y)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QJeUIstYi0kisYGh)

**Update:** Added visualizations.

Comment: Thanks very much! This does the trick: 
> gsub("([^%])y", "\\1*", "%x%xxxx_y_%y%y")
[1] "%x%xxxx_*_%y%y"

Answer (score 1):

You could try the regex `lookbehind`

```
 gsub("(?<=[^%])y", "", "%x%xxxx_y_%y%y", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "%x%xxxx__%y%y"
```

Can we viewed at [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/oG5dI9/1)

```
(?<=[^%])y
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Quite interesting solution, too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this case , you could use positive lookbehind or capturing group or `\K` (*which discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final*).

```
> gsub("[^%]\\Ky", "*", "%x%xxxx_y_%y%y", perl=TRUE)
[1] "%x%xxxx_*_%y%y"
```

[\K](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/oG5dI9/2)